# jQuery How to change row background color, fror each separate row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have such question, how i can change background color for each separate row?

For example i have table

For this to rows i wanna make another color, **for example red**.

HTML:

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tableData">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var lpmsData = [
    { item: "111000355B", order: "9999999999", actual: "403", target: "404", defects: "1", efficiency: 89, pefomance: 78, oee: "N/A", startTime: "06:45:44" },
    { item: "102211549B", order: "8888888887", actual: "504", target: "366", defects: "123", efficiency: 125, pefomance: 96, oee: "N/A", startTime: "05:35:64" }
];

var timeShedule = [
    { firstShift: ["05:45 - 07:00", "07:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00", "10:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 13:00", "13:00 - 14:00", "14:00 - 14:45",]}
];

function buildTable() {
    $.each(lpmsData, function (i, data) {
        var categoryBuild = '<tr><td width="150">' + timeShedule[0].firstShift[i] + '</td><td>' + data.item + '</td><td>' + data.actual + '</td><td>' + data.target + '</td><td>' + data.defects + '</td><td>' + data.efficiency + '</td><td>' + data.pefomance + '</td><td>' + data.oee + '</td></tr>';
        if (data.efficiency <= 50) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        }
        $('.tableData').append(categoryBuild);
    });

}
```

I try to use this type of code, but recived:

So any idea how to do it?

Comment: Assuming that you are looping over each row, use `$(this).css("background-color", "blue");`

Comment: please show how you are creating the table and also the html

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes i use loop, but this code not working

Comment: @qunz666 then you have to provide us with your HTML table and the corresponding jQuery code.

Comment: @brk edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `if` statement after your `append` method:

```
$('.tableData').append(categoryBuild);
if (data.efficiency <= 50) {
  $('.tableData tr:last').css("background-color", "blue");
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var lpmsData = [{
    item: "111000355B",
    order: "9999999999",
    actual: "403",
    target: "404",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 89,
    pefomance: 78,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "06:45:44"
  },
  {
    item: "102211549B",
    order: "8888888887",
    actual: "504",
    target: "366",
    defects: "123",
    efficiency: 125,
    pefomance: 96,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "05:35:64"
  },
  {
    item: "112255458C",
    order: "7777777777",
    actual: "777",
    target: "555",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 155,
    pefomance: 102,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "07:44:44"
  },
  {
    item: "111225445G",
    order: "6666666666",
    actual: "403",
    target: "404",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 34,
    pefomance: 78,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "11:55:09"
  },
  {
    item: "584844455A",
    order: "5555555555",
    actual: "905",
    target: "905",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 100,
    pefomance: 78,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "12:45:44"
  },
  {
    item: "111000354B",
    order: "9999999999",
    actual: "403",
    target: "404",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 89,
    pefomance: 78,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "13:45:44"
  },
  {
    item: "102253212B",
    order: "8888888887",
    actual: "504",
    target: "366",
    defects: "123",
    efficiency: 125,
    pefomance: 96,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "13:55:44"
  },
  {
    item: "112241678C",
    order: "7777777777",
    actual: "777",
    target: "555",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 50,
    pefomance: 102,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "14:15:44"
  },
  {
    item: "111225456G",
    order: "6666666666",
    actual: "403",
    target: "404",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 89,
    pefomance: 78,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "14:22:46"
  },
  {
    item: "584844000A",
    order: "5555555555",
    actual: "905",
    target: "905",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 100,
    pefomance: 78,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "14:36:13"
  }
];

var timeShedule = [{
  firstShift: ["05:45 - 07:00", "07:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00", "10:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 13:00", "13:00 - 14:00", "14:00 - 14:45", ]
}];

buildTable()

function buildTable() {
  $.each(lpmsData, function(i, data) {
    var categoryBuild = '<tr><td width="150">' + timeShedule[0].firstShift[i] + '</td><td>' + data.item + '</td><td>' + data.actual + '</td><td>' + data.target + '</td><td>' + data.defects + '</td><td>' + data.efficiency + '</td><td>' + data.pefomance + '</td><td>' + data.oee + '</td></tr>';
    if (data.efficiency <= 50) {
      categoryBuild = $($.parseHTML(categoryBuild))
      categoryBuild.css("background-color", "blue");
    }
    $('.tableData').append(categoryBuild);
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Item number</th>
      <th>Actual</th>
      <th>Target</th>
      <th>Defects</th>
      <th>Efficiency</th>
      <th>Performance</th>
      <th>OEE</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tableData">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

An alternative way is to do it like this:

```
if (data.efficiency <= 50) {
  categoryBuild = $($.parseHTML(categoryBuild))
  categoryBuild.css("background-color", "blue");
}
```

Comment: @qunz666 try look at the second way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template literals and add a class to `tr`.`<tr class="${data.efficiency<=50?'blue':''}">` is checking if the value of data.efficiency is less than or equal to 50. If so a class will be added to `tr`

```js
var lpmsData = [{
    item: "111000355B",
    order: "9999999999",
    actual: "403",
    target: "404",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 89,
    pefomance: 78,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "06:45:44"
  },
  {
    item: "102211549B",
    order: "8888888887",
    actual: "504",
    target: "366",
    defects: "123",
    efficiency: 125,
    pefomance: 96,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "05:35:64"
  },
  {
    item: "112255458C",
    order: "7777777777",
    actual: "777",
    target: "555",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 155,
    pefomance: 102,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "07:44:44"
  },
  {
    item: "111225445G",
    order: "6666666666",
    actual: "403",
    target: "404",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 34,
    pefomance: 78,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "11:55:09"
  },
  {
    item: "584844455A",
    order: "5555555555",
    actual: "905",
    target: "905",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 100,
    pefomance: 78,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "12:45:44"
  },
  {
    item: "111000354B",
    order: "9999999999",
    actual: "403",
    target: "404",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 89,
    pefomance: 78,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "13:45:44"
  },
  {
    item: "102253212B",
    order: "8888888887",
    actual: "504",
    target: "366",
    defects: "123",
    efficiency: 125,
    pefomance: 96,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "13:55:44"
  },
  {
    item: "112241678C",
    order: "7777777777",
    actual: "777",
    target: "555",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 50,
    pefomance: 102,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "14:15:44"
  },
  {
    item: "111225456G",
    order: "6666666666",
    actual: "403",
    target: "404",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 89,
    pefomance: 78,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "14:22:46"
  },
  {
    item: "584844000A",
    order: "5555555555",
    actual: "905",
    target: "905",
    defects: "1",
    efficiency: 100,
    pefomance: 78,
    oee: "N/A",
    startTime: "14:36:13"
  }
];

var timeShedule = [{
  firstShift: ["05:45 - 07:00", "07:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00", "10:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 13:00", "13:00 - 14:00", "14:00 - 14:45", ]
}];

function buildTable() {
  $.each(lpmsData, function(i, data) {
    var categoryBuild = `<tr class=${data.efficiency<=50?"blue":""}>
    <td width="150">${timeShedule[0].firstShift[i]}</td>
    <td>${data.item}</td>
    <td>${data.actual}</td> 
    <td>${data.target}</td>
    <td>${data.defects}</td>
    <td>${data.efficiency}</td>
    <td>${data.pefomance}</td>
    <td>$data.oee}</td>
    </tr>`;

    $('.tableData').append(categoryBuild);
  });

}
buildTable()
```

```css
.blue {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Item number</th>
      <th>Actual</th>
      <th>Target</th>
      <th>Defects</th>
      <th>Efficiency</th>
      <th>Performance</th>
      <th>OEE</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tableData">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pure CSS?

```
 tbody.tableData tr:nth-child(even) {background: red;}
```